# how to symbolicate a crash file that has framework dsyms as well

Tags: xcode, symbolicatecrash

My app contains multiple frameworks. So I have the framework code as dSYM files as well. Right now I symbolicate against one dSYM file and use the output for the next dSYM file and so on. Is there a way I can point all the dSYMs at once.

I came across a tool symbolicate-crash in git but that throws me an error the the framework dSYM are from a different built. I verified the uuids and of course they work with symbolicatecrash

Kindly advice